# A Rails CMS that support local theming natively with HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, haml, refinerycms, locomotivecms

I would like to know if there is any CMS that supports local theme editing ? I mean, one the best rails CMS, locomotiveCMS need an extra paying tool called LocomotiveEditor if you want to code localy,

I also tried Refinery CMS, a good one too, but it look a pain to code HAML.

Or is there another method to do that ?

The only thing i hate is to code in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locomotive has since done away with the Editor and started using a tool called Wagon that does almost the same thing but is open source as well. You may want check it out.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I discovered that also, and Wagon Editor is really good

Answer (score 0):

[Radiant CMS](https://github.com/radiant/radiant) uses HAML, not used it myself but might be worth a look.

Comment: but it's in browser no ? it look like :
http://demo.radiantcms.org/admin/pages/1/edit

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you could pull the code from github and edit it using your editor of choice. The link you have shown is to Radiant when it is set up, so this would be in the browser to enable your users to edit the website using the CMS right?

Comment: i mean, the theme editing is in the browser not in rails views ?
like something : app/views/welcome/index.erb.haml
i am talking about the theming, not the content editing.
Can i use Radiant CMS like that ? because, i saw that : http://ext.radiantcms.org/extensions/145-haml-filter 
If this is what you are talking about, it is about the content (in browser editing), not the theming (Rails views) ? but i will try Radiant before talking too much :D thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit old but for the sake of answering. RefineryCMS allows you to override views for default pages and also create Custom view templates and custom layout templates.

You can refer to that via: 
http://refinerycms.com/guides/using-custom-view-or-layout-templates